# 3D figure in tikzfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I would like to generate a 3D plot with axis in tikzfigure, and I know it very much possible on `matplotlib`. But, I'm not sure how to do this in `tikzfigure`. [image]

Please let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->] (0,0,0)-- node[below] {Beta} ++(6,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,7,0) node[midway, left=7mm,rotate=90]{Delta};
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,0,6) node[midway, sloped, above] {Constraint};

\draw[-] (1,-.3,0) node[below]{1}--(1,.3,0);
\draw[-] (5,-.3,0) node[below]{5}--(5,.3,0);

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}
    \draw[dashed] (0,\i,0) node[left] {\i} --++(5,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: A 3D point**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->] (0,0,0)-- node[pos=.7,below] {Beta} ++(6,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,7,0) node[pos=.75, left=7mm,rotate=90]{Delta};
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,0,6) node[midway, sloped, above] {Constraint};

\draw[-] (1,-.3,0) node[below]{1}--(1,.3,0);
\draw[-] (5,-.3,0) node[below]{5}--(5,.3,0);

%\foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}
%   \draw[dashed] (0,\i,0) node[left] {\i} --++(5,0,0);

\fill (3,4,3) circle(3pt);

\draw[dashed] (3,4,3)--(3,4,0)--(0,4,0)--(0,4,3)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (3,4,3)--(3,0,3)--(3,0,0)--(3,4,0);
\draw[dashed] (3,0,3)--(0,0,3)--(0,4,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prototype. I was wondering how to make it a bit more realistic i.e., how do we show a 3D point in that figure?

Comment: @tandem Is it better now?

Comment: That looks fantastic if i say so myself!